# saved data frame is not shown correctly in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, utf-8, rodbc

I have data frame named `distTest` which have columns with `UTF-8` format. I want to save  the `distTest` as table in my `sql database`. My code is as follows;

```
library(RODBC)
load("distTest.RData")
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "persian")
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=****;database=TestDB;
                               trusted_connection=true',DBMSencoding="UTF-8" )
Encoding(distTest$regsub)<-"UTF-8"
Encoding(distTest$subgroup)<-"UTF-8"
sqlSave(dbhandle,distTest,
        tablename = "DistBars", verbose = T, rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

I considered `DBMSencoding` for my connection and encodings `Encoding(distTest$regsub)<-"UTF-8"`
`Encoding(distTest$subgroup)<-"UTF-8"`
for my columns. However, when I save it to sql the columns are not shown in correct format, and they are like this;[image]

When I set `fast` in `sqlSave` function to `FALSE`, I got this error;

> Error in sqlSave(dbhandle, Distbars, tablename = "DistBars", verbose =
>   T,  :    22001 8152 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]String or binary data would be truncated. 01000 3621
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been
>   terminated. [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'INSERT INTO
>   "DistBars" ( "regsub", "week", "S", "A", "F", "labeled_cluster",
>   "subgroup", "windows" ) VALUES ( 'Ø¸â€',  5, 4, 2, 3, 'cl1', 'Ø·Â­Ø¸â€¦Ø¸â€ž
>   Ø·Â²Ø·Â¨Ø·Â§Ø¸â€žØ¸â€¡',  1 )'

I also tried `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for `utf-8`  column in the design of table with `fast=false` the error gone, but the same error with format.

By the way, a part of data is exported as `RData` in [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwlpBJQ2GUBiWWdCckhsa3VrUWc/view).

I want to know why the data format is not shown correctly in `sql server 2016`?

**UPDATE**

I am fully assured that there is something wrong with `RODBC` package.
I tried inserting to table by 
`sqlQuery(channel = dbhandle,"insert into DistBars 
          values(N'7من',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)")`

as a test, and the format is still wrong. Unfortunately, adding `CharSet=utf8;` to connection string does not either work.

Comment: I know nothing about `r`, but Sql Server's nvarchar / nchar are used for unicode values. My bet is that the problem is before the string even gets to sql server, as implied by the error messag.

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled but I used Nvarchar for utf-8 columns. I agree with you about the problem before export.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my code and I managed to fix it eliminating `rows_at_time = 1` from my connection configuration.